# Give randomly Combination of Strings in TextFields each time on button click?

Tags: java, string, swing

I'm making a Fixture Generator and need to generate random matching of items (teams) each time a button is clicked.

I m using a static String Array to hold the teams inputed by the user.

```
String s[]=new String[3];
s[0]="team1";
s[1]="team2";
s[2]="team3";
```

How can I shuffle this array?

Is it possible to get every possible combination of strings?

Comment: Here is a similar questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array

Comment: `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array));`

Comment: @JB You should post that as an answer, preferably with links to the relevant docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this to generate the teams and shuffle them:

```
// Using a list.
final int teamCount = 10;
final List<String> teams = new ArrayList<>();
for (int teamIndex = 0; teamIndex < teamCount; teamIndex++)
    teams.add("team" + (teamIndex + 1));
Collections.shuffle(teams);
System.out.println("teams: " + teams);

// Using an array.
final int teamCount = 10;
final String[] teams = new String[teamCount];
for (int teamIndex = 0; teamIndex < teamCount; teamIndex++)
    teams[teamIndex] = "team" + (teamIndex + 1);
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(teams));
System.out.println("teams: " + Arrays.toString(teams));
```